# Why does Option[Try[_]] not conform to F[_]?

Tags: scala, types, higher-kinded-types, type-kinds, kind-projector

So having something like this:

```
@ trait IntWrapper[F[_]] { def apply(i: Int): F[Int] }
defined trait IntWrapper

@ class OptWrapper extends IntWrapper[Option] { def apply(i: Int) = Option(i) }
defined class OptWrapper
```

I now want to do something like this:

```
@ class TryOptWrapper extends IntWrapper[Try[Option]] { def apply(i: Int) = Try(Option(i)) }
cmd19.sc:1: scala.util.Try[Option] takes no type parameters, expected: one
class TryOptWrapper extends IntWrapper[Try[Option]] { def apply(i: Int) = Try(Option(i)) }
                                       ^
Compilation Failed
```

(Same thing if I declare the trait extension as `class TryOptWrapper extends IntWrapper[Try[Option[_]]]`)

Now, perhaps the most interestingly, this works:

```
@ type Topt[T] = Try[Option[T]]

@ class ToptWrapper extends IntWrapper[Topt] { def apply(i: Int) = Try(Option(i)) }
defined class ToptWrapper
```

Now, is it possible to do the same thing – i.e. implement a trait with a type parameter being a *nested* parametrized type – without having to explicitly declare the type alias? It definitely feels like I'm missing some syntax here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Try` expects type parameter of kind `*` and `Option` has kind `* => *` so you can't write `Try[Option]`, only `Try[Option[Int]]`, `Try[Option[String]]`, `Try[Option[_]]`...

Try type lambda

```
class TryOptWrapper extends IntWrapper[({ type λ[A] = Try[Option[A]] })#λ] { def apply(i: Int) = Try(Option(i)) }
```

Or with [kind-projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector)

```
class TryOptWrapper extends IntWrapper[Lambda[A => Try[Option[A]]]] { def apply(i: Int) = Try(Option(i)) }
```